# Which icon set is the notification bar and the pull down notification menu in android?

Tags: android, notifications, icons

In android I want to add icons for the notification bar. The problem is I don't know which group the notification bar is. In eclipse, I can make

-Launcher icon

-action bar and tab icons

-notification bar

I have the launcher icons done, and I don't need action bar and tab icons.
I have the notification icons, but when I look at the outlook icon for example. There is one on the notification bar and then if I slide down the menu on top (the one that shows wifi/gps/vibrate/rotate/etc... buttons) I see a bigger outlook icon which is more white and more opaque.

Do both of these belong to notification bar icon set? How are they showing two different types of icons for the notifications?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should review the "Iconography" guidelines for notifications:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

To quote from the docs:

> "Notification icons must be entirely white. Also, the system may scale
>   down and/or darken the icons."

I don't think wihte-only icons are always appropriate. However, the scaling and darkening have to do with Android themes. Bright white notifications may appear to "diminish" the theme being presented. Similarly, dim or dull icons may get washed out.

So, it makes sense that as a general rule Android guidelines would suggest basic assumptions about your icon (in this case, they assume "all white" and flat). That allows them to develop themes for the wide variety of versions, manufacturers, platforms and carriers available.

In other words, even if you don't like them, it's probably best to follow them (which I generally do).